# Is this a bug in the g++ for-loop implementation or in my code

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, vulkan

I am currently working on a Vulkan project. I have 2 images in my swap chain, but my application iterates over it more than 2 times. I can't see what's wrong, and CLion, g++ and clang++ don't throw any warnings.

```
    std::cout << vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainImageCount << std::endl;

    for (uint32_t swapchainImageIndex = 0;
         swapchainImageIndex < vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainImageCount; swapchainImageIndex++) {
        std::cout << "is " << swapchainImageIndex << " < " << vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainImageCount << " "
                  << getTruthValue(swapchainImageIndex < vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainImageCount) << std::endl;

        VkImageViewCreateInfo imageViewCreateInfo = {};
        imageViewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
        imageViewCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        imageViewCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        imageViewCreateInfo.image = vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainImages[swapchainImageIndex];
        imageViewCreateInfo.format = vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainFormat;
        imageViewCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
        imageViewCreateInfo.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R;
        imageViewCreateInfo.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G;
        imageViewCreateInfo.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B;
        imageViewCreateInfo.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
        std::cout << "a " << swapchainImageIndex << std::endl;
        VULKAN_ASSERT(vkCreateImageView(vulkanRendererInternalInfo.device, &imageViewCreateInfo, nullptr,
                                        &vulkanRendererInternalInfo.swapchainImageViews[swapchainImageIndex]))
    }
```

`getTruthValue` returns "True" or "False", `VULKAN_ASSERT` is a macro to check for VkResult. The first two times VkResult is VK_SUCCESS and the third time vkCreateImageView creates a segmentation fault.

When I compile with `g++ -O3 -march=skylake -ffast-math ...` or `g++ -O3 ...` or `g++ -O1 ...`

```
2
is 0 < 2 True
a 0
is 1 < 2 True
a 1
is 2 < 2 False
a 2
UNASSIGNED-GeneralParameterError-RequiredParameter(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -1711571459 - Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-GeneralParameterError-RequiredParameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x562a0969f6a8, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x99fb7dfd | vkCreateImageView: required parameter pCreateInfo->image specified as VK_NULL_HANDLE
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x562a0969f6a8, type: 3, name: NULL
VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-image-parameter(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 315335852 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-image-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x562a089cb8a0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0x12cba4ac | Invalid VkImage Object 0x0. The Vulkan spec states: image must be a valid VkImage handle (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-image-parameter)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x562a089cb8a0, type: 1, name: NULL
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But it works when I use `g++ -O0 -march=skylake -ffast-math ...` or `clang++ -O3 -march=skylake -ffast-math ...`

Comment: If I remove the Vulkan API call, this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it is a bug since I could fix it by adding `return 0;` after the if statement.

Comment: More often than not those mysterious errors are caused by UB in your code, rather than compiler bugs.

Comment: Yes, and the code you shared contains no if I can see

Comment: @holy to back up the cat, I have seen 100s of bugs like this where there was UB and unrelated code changes "fixed" it, and have found at most a handful of compiler bugs this way, in my life.  I cannot even guess why you are seeing it, as UB code comes in dozens upon dozens of flavours.  From the pedestrian (didn't initialize a variable, following dead pointers, buffer overruns, etc), to the insane (ODR violations, aliasing UB, etc)